# Can I use sentiment analysis techniques and text processing for detection social bot in online social networks?

Tags: machine-learning, social-network-analysis

I want to study in field of " Detecting fake account on online social network by content/sentiment analysis " for Master's Thesis.is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it has been done before:

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2808779